# Time quantum per process per thread

Tags: c, windows, linux, kernel

I have a question pertaining to time quantum given to processes and threads in windows and linux.

I know operating systems in general give a fixed amount of time quantum per thread. (I know time quantum changes depending on foreground or background threads. May also change depending on the priority of a process.)

Is there a fixed time quantum per process? For eg. If OS gives 36 time quantum per process and if a process has 2 threads then each will get 18 quantum. If number of threads becomes 3 then each will get 12.

However, if a fixed quantum per process does not exist and OS gives fix quantum per thread(No dependency on the parent process.) then I may be able to make my process more efficient by spawning multiple threads.(Assuming I dont have two many mutex/semaphores in my code.)

I have an application which runs on both OS(Windows and linux). So, I am asking it in a general sense.

Thanks

Comment: Where did this awful term 'quantum' come from?  99.99% of all threads never run for anything approaching the OS timer scheduling interval before getting blocked on I/O, another thread or some other system call. I thought 'quanta' were supposed to be indivisible?  Stupid term that gives misleading impressions!

Comment: You may wanna check this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259025

Comment: smith - M$, I should'a guessed...

Answer (score 1):

On linux from a scheduling perspective threads and processes are equivalent. So if a process spawns two threads, each should get 36 quantum. Although I would like to hear this from someone with greater credibility than mine to confirm.

Comment: Windows too.  The scheduler deals with threads, not processes.

Comment: @Harry: In that case, a process can steal more time by having multiple threads. Is this statement right?

Comment: Yes, although calling it "stealing" seems slightly odd. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Quite an interesting question :)

I do not really have the exact details, but from the link below you can see that the modern OS has an estimate based method of thread scheduling.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.02.vistakernel.aspx