# Manipulate switching between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization, parallel.for

How many times(how offen) per second parallel.for switching between threads? Can I manage this parameter? 
I would like understand how it works on low level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time quantum per process per thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116363/time-quantum-per-process-per-thread)

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be managed by the operating system, and it has a wide latitude in how, specifically, it goes about scheduling threads.  Different operating systems also leverage subtly or even widely varying approaches for scheduling threads.

You have control over what threads are eligible to be scheduled, and in some operating systems limited control over prioritization (the specifics of which will vary based on the OS) but that's pretty much it.